# Puxando elementos de uma lista para outra sob um critério no R

Tags: r

O vetor abaixo indica as regressões que eu rodei.

```
regression_pairs=c("A~B", "C~D", "E~F", "G~H","I~J","K~L","M~N","O~P","Q~R")

regression_pairs
```

Abaixo esta a lista onde eu guardei os residuos de cada regressão `residuals.new`:

```
    residuals.new <- list()
     a=c(1,2,3,4,5)
 b=c(6,7,8,9,10)
 c=c(11,12,13,14,15)
 d=c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
 e=c(21,22,23,24,25)
 f=c(26,27,28,29,30)
 g=c(31,32,33,34,35)
 h=c(36,37,38,39,40)
 i=c(41,42,43,44,45)

 residuals.new[[1]]=a
 residuals.new[[2]]=b
 residuals.new[[3]]=c
 residuals.new[[4]]=d
 residuals.new[[5]]=e
residuals.new[[6]]=f
residuals.new[[7]]=g
residuals.new[[8]]=h
residuals.new[[9]]=i

residuals.new
```

Ou seja, os residuos da regressão `A~B` são `1,2,3,4,5` , os residuos da regressão C~D são `6,7,8,9,10` e por aí vai.

Depois de um determinado criterio vi que os melhores pares são os representados pela lista abaixo:

```
bestresults<-list()

best_pairs=c("A~B", "G~H", "Q~R")
```

Agora eu preciso descobrir uma forma de criar uma lista que pegue os residuos referentes as regressões apresentada pela lista `best_pairs`.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Abaixo esta o resultado que eu busco:

```
the.bestresiduals<-list()

 the.bestresiduals[[1]]=c(1,2,3,4,5)
 the.bestresiduals[[2]]=c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
 the.bestresiduals[[3]]=c(41,42,43,44,45)

the.bestresiduals

    [[1]]
    [1] 1 2 3 4 5

    [[2]]
    [1] 16 17 18 19 20

    [[3]]
    [1] 41 42 43 44 45
```

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função **match** ela retornará a posição dos elementos de **best_pairs** no vetor **regression_pairs**

```
regression_pairs=c("A~B", "C~D", "E~F", "G~H","I~J","K~L","M~N","O~P","Q~R")

residuals.new <- list(
                        a=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                        b=c(6,7,8,9,10),
                        c=c(11,12,13,14,15),
                        d=c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
                        e=c(21,22,23,24,25),
                        f=c(26,27,28,29,30),
                        g=c(31,32,33,34,35),
                        h=c(36,37,38,39,40),
                        i=c(41,42,43,44,45)
                      )

best_pairs=c("A~B", "G~H", "Q~R")

residuals.new[c(match(best_pairs, regression_pairs))]
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#$d
#[1] 16 17 18 19 20

#$i
#[1] 41 42 43 44 45
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a função `%in%`. Se for usada como

```
x %in% y
```

ela cruza `x` com `y`. Ele retorna um vetor do tamanho de `x`,
informando o índice em `y` no qual se encontram os elementos de `x`. Na prática, veja o que ocorre no teu problema:

```
regression_pairs %in% best_pairs
TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Se eu salvar este resultado num vetor chamado `indices`, o que obtenho é

```
indices <- regression_pairs %in% best_pairs
residuals.new[indices]

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 16 17 18 19 20

[[3]]
[1] 41 42 43 44 45
```

Mais informações podem ser encontradas no help da função: `?match` (sim, `match` é equivalente a `%in%`, não se preocupe).